# how to link dynamic dropdown to different pages

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

This is the dynamic link from category table join to news table so i want to link in `<li>` to different page like `allnational`, `allsports` (these are the things in dropdown) function in home controller:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <?php if($category){
        foreach($category as $c){
            ?>
        <li><a href=""><?php echo $c['category_name'];?></a></li>
        <?php }} ?>
  </ul>
```

just want to add link in above `href`
table scheme:

`category_id: 1 , 2 , 3
category_name: national , international , sports`

***"category_id & category_name are column and its value listed above respectively"***

Home controller:

```
public function allnational(){
    $data['allnat'] = $this->newsmodel->getAllNational();
    $this->load->view('allnational',$data);
}
public function allInternational(){
    $data['allint'] = $this->newsmodel->getAllInternational();
    $this->load->view('allinternational',$data);
}
```

if you can give suggestion what will be the model as well.

Note: model is already loaded.

Comment: can you please show the table schema?

Comment: And show both your models And re edit your question with them by clicking on edit below tags.

Comment: how to send a table man i can't post picture and file

Comment: explain the table schema, with column names at least.

Comment: if this dropdown is in your common file.just use any variable and value for that variable will be assigned by your controller like this `$data['category'] = something`.

Comment: thanks for your corporation, the problem has been solved... thanks all of you